# Get (error) messages out of a class

Tags: php, class, message

If I have a `model` login (class `Login`) that when posted to from a `login.php` (the form) operates as any other login script. If an error occurs it dumps the error into a public function within the class.

```
public function displayMessageEntry($error, $exit = NULL) {

    if( !empty($error) ) :

        return $error;

    endif;

}
```

via `$this->error ? self::displayMessageEntry($this->error, false) : self::displayMessageEntry($this->msg, false);`

This works all fine when I was using simple templates as I would just echo it out and it would appear in the `body` portion when I had a head, body, and footer includes, **however my design has gotten more complex, and I cannot seem to figure out how to access the `$error` data (if any), via something like this: `<?php echo isset($err) ? $err : NULL; ?>` called on the login page itself**. Under previous login scripts I used I would just have the procedural code under an `isset($_POST)` and then any errors or messages would be added to an array and parsed the aforementioned way. ***Is there any way of doing this given the layout I mentioned?***

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Was as simple as `<?php echo isset($login->error) ? $login->error : ''; ?>` and modifying the display function to:

```
public function displayMessageEntry($error, $exit = NULL) {

    if( !empty($error) ) :

        $this->error;

    endif;

}
```